# Remove class="form-item" from Drupal forms

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms

Drupal automatically adds <div>'s and classes around form items. All form elements will have the attribute `class = "form-item"`. How do I override this default behavior?

Comment: Consider editing the CSS instead, to reach the desired effects.

Comment: I would've done that. But in my company CSS is the property of the designer and developers are not to edit them. And also my project leader insists on finding a proper workaround, other than editing the css :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on changing it, it's added in the [theme_form_element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_form_element/6) function. You can override it by copying that function to your theme's template.php file and renaming it THEMENAME_form_element (substituting the name of your theme in place of "THEMENAME") or phptemplate_form_element and removing the part that adds the class.

Comment: Thanks. That's absolutely what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

In real experience these are useful classes, but if you want to extremely clear form you can theme each form element or theme form:
Much closer to your task i found here (not only zen theme and not only for user login block): [Custom User Login Block on Drupal 6 Zen sub-themes](http://www.anthonymclin.com/code/7-miscellaneous/96-custom-user-login-block-on-drupal-6-zen-sub-themes) in "Advanced theming" part, see bottom code.